# ASP.NET 4 MVC System Requirements (for Sever Deployment)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Not sure why I haven't been able to find this yet. When I Google for this, for the official release notes I get this: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253805 which says:

> The ASP.NET MVC 4 components for Visual Studio require PowerShell 2.0
>   and either Visual Studio 2010 with Service Pack 1 or Visual Web
>   Developer Express 2010 with Service Pack 1.

The ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta site lists the server system requirements. I think I can assume that these are still what's required, but it would be *nice* to get the list from the official release:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28942

> System requirements Supported operating systems: Windows 7, Windows
>   Server 2003 R2 (32-Bit x86), Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 editions,
>   Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2008, Windows
>   Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista Service Pack 2, Windows XP Service Pack
>   3
>
> Additional Requirements: PowerShell 2.0, .NET 4, ASP.NET 4, and Visual
>   Studio 2010 SP1 or Visual Web Developer 2010 SP1 are required to use
>   this feature.

I suppose I am just being stubborn about this, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: trying to find this myself...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any official source for the server requirements of the release version.  Looks like they left that out of the release notes.