# Does hosting for Asp.Net web forms application differ from Asp.Net MVC application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, hosting, web-hosting

Does hosting for Asp.Net web forms application differ from Asp.Net MVC application, or It doesn't matter as far as the server supports IIS, .Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not different. You just have publish the site and deploy on the server. There is difference in files you got after publishing site.

Comment: thanks. What if I am using Entity Framework? Does that make any difference?

Comment: still its does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

According to this SO answer, no, it's all the same.  IIS.

[ASP.NET MVC - Server software requirements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372701/asp-net-mvc-server-software-requirements)

[ASP.NET 4 MVC System Requirements (for Sever Deployment)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757840/asp-net-4-mvc-system-requirements-for-sever-deployment)

Comment: What if I am using Entity Framework? Does that make any difference?